# CreateDirectory with AjaxFileUpload into a specific folder

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create a folder then upload documents to that same folder with AjaxFileUpload function, and I need the folder path to include the value of a text box in my form; however, I cannot seem to find any good resources to show me how to do so, so any help would be appreciated.  Here is my code:

aspx page (the below is within an update panel):

```
                    <asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="CertificateUpload" ThrobberID="myThrobber" runat="server" MaximumNumberOfFiles="10" Width="600px" OnUploadStart="CreateFolder_Click" OnUploadComplete="File_Upload" />
```

apsx.cs page:

```
    protected void CreateFolder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string folderName = @"P:\Training Records\Training Detail Records\Individual Records";
    string pathString = Path.Combine(folderName, firstnametier1.Text + " " + lastnametier1.Text);

    if (!Directory.Exists(pathString))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString);
    }
}

protected void File_Upload(object sender, AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
        string filename = e.FileName;
        string FinalFolder = "~/Training Detail Records/Individual Records/";
        string strDestPath = Server.MapPath(@FinalFolder);
        CertificateUpload.SaveAs(@strDestPath + filename);
}
```

}

I am trying to put the these two together so the folder gets created if necessary when I hit the upload button and I would like to add an extra text value to the final folder path like this:

```
string FinalFolder = "~/Training Detail Records/Individual Records/" + Textbox.Text + "/";
```

But when I try this it does not work.  Again, any help will be welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

Here is the code for the aspx.cs page:

first I added the following to the SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) section:

```
            string fullname = firstnametier1.Text + " " + lastnametier1.Text;
        Session["fname"] = fullname;
```

That helped store the value of the two text fields in the session so I could use it in the ajaxfileupload function.

Second I adjusted my other piece of code like so:

```
    protected void File_Upload(object sender, AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
    string folderName = "P:/Training Records/Training Detail Records/Individual Records/" + Session["fname"].ToString() + "/";

    if (!Directory.Exists(folderName))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(folderName));
    }
        string filename = e.FileName;
        string strDestPath = Server.MapPath(@folderName);
        CertificateUpload.SaveAs(@strDestPath + filename);
}
```

And now it works! I am creating a folder with the name I want and adding the data to it.

I am not a professional programmer so if you see any issues with this code or can make it better, please do so. I hope this helps other people.